# Why does the first code NOT cause a dead-lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
std::mutex mtx;

void func2() {
    mtx.lock();
    std::cout << "here is 2" << std::endl;
    mtx.unlock();
}

void func1() {
    mtx.lock();
    std::cout << "here is 1" << std::endl;
    func2();
    mtx.unlock();
}

int main() {
    func1();
}
```

but if I modify the main func as follows, it cause dead lock

```
int main() {
    std::thread t1(func1);
    t1.join();
}
```

I complied both two by "`g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread`"

Comment: To have a real dead lock you need at least two threads holding each holding at least two mutexes. So even though your code some problems it can't have a dead lock, since you have one thread and one mutex.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock): `"If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: for example, the program may deadlock."`.  So both code snippets exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: as to why behaviour is different in first case is likely related to quirks of CriticalSection on Windows. It's Windows, right?

Comment: I think that some implementations can detect when a program never calls any function that could start a thread.  In such a case, all calls to mutex functions can be optimized away, since no mutex can ever be contended (without causing UB as your program does) and so no mutex calls can have any observable effect.  That may be the explanation for the particular type of UB you are noticing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `lock` in the same thread twice (without unlocking the mutex) is undefined. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: for example, the program may deadlock.

It may deadlock. Or it may not. The behavior is undefined.

Note that [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) can be locked multiple times (though only up to some unspecified limit). However, code that needs a recursive mutex is more complicated. In your example it would be easier to remove the locking from `func1`, because it is only called when the mutex is already locked. In general it isn't that simple.